# Making NSMutableAttributedString and sizeThatFits work together

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I'm having issues making NSMutableAttributedString and sizeThatFits work together. I have a UILabel that must be no wider than a constant `self.frame.size.width-usernameX-horizontalMargin`. I want the UILabel to be one line if it fits or two lines with a hyphen if it is too long. Currently I am using this code:

```
let usernameX = profilePhoto.frame.size.width+horizontalMargin
let username = UILabel()
username.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false
username.font = UIFont(name: "SFUIDisplay-Regular", size: 18)
username.numberOfLines = 0
username.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

//Set hyphenation
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.hyphenationFactor = 0.2
username.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: displayName, attributes: [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle])
let maxSize = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width-usernameX-horizontalMargin, height: CGFloat.max)
let requiredSize = username.sizeThatFits(maxSize)
username.frame = CGRect(x: usernameX, y: (self.frame.size.height/2)-21, width: requiredSize.width, height: requiredSize.height)

self.addSubview(username)
```

Currently the text displays as just one line with a hyphen. The second line isn't showing. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here? I have tried setting the number of lines to 2, that made no difference. Any pointers would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your font also in attributes, else it will take default fond for attributed text. Can you try this out?

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: displayName, attributes: [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle, NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "SFUIDisplay-Regular", size: 18)])
var newFrame = attributedString.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width-usernameX-horizontalMargin, CGFloat.max), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin , context: nil)
username.frame = CGRect(x: usernameX, y: (self.frame.size.height/2)-21, width: newFrame.size.width, height: newFrame.size.height)
```

If you want to use `sizeThatFits` you can use following

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.hyphenationFactor = 0.2
username.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: displayName, attributes: [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle, NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "SFUIDisplay-Regular", size: 18)])
let maxSize = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width-usernameX-horizontalMargin, height: CGFloat.max)
let requiredSize = username.sizeThatFits(maxSize)
username.frame = CGRect(x: usernameX, y: (self.frame.size.height/2)-21, width: requiredSize.width, height: requiredSize.height)

self.addSubview(username)
```

Comment: Just tried your code. No difference there. I wonder if the constraints are affecting it...

Comment: Can you set height constraint for your label and change it at runtime?